# Can I capitalize first letter of a string defined through a dynamicresource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, globalization, multiple-languages

I am developing a WPF software and I need to handle multiple languages. In order to do that, I am going to use `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` to know in which language I should display the UI.

In order to do so, I am writing ResourceDictionaries made with these kind of resources :

```
  <system:String x:Key="close">close</system:String>
```

I am wondering something : in the case I need to use "close" and "Close" (difference is the capital letter on the first letter), do I have to write it twice and make a difference on the `x:Key` such as `close_lc` and `close_uc` or is there a way around so that I don't have to write every word / sentence twice ?

I thought I could do this by making my own Converter and use it like this :

```
<Button Content={DynamicResource close, Converter={StaticResource FirstLetterUpperCaseConverter}}/>
```

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use converters on dynamic resources...

Thanks, .x

Comment: Actually, you shouldn’t identify resources on their content, but on their usage for which you are going to use. So a suffix `_uc` or `_lc` would be far too specific for the primary language and wouldn’t include any information on what the text is used for.

Comment: @poke Well, my example might not be a good one. In cases of buttons which does basics actions such as closing the app, I've to have this kind of resources and keys ("close/close", "open/open"), ain't I? But anyway, if I understood you well, you suggest me to write this kind of stuff `<system:String x:Key="openfolder">Are you sure you want to open this folder ?</system:String>` ? (if not, i didn't understand, maybe do you have an example for me ?^^)

Comment: Well, I would probably make it even more specific, e.g. `openFolderConfirmation`. And for the close/open, I would split it up, so I don’t reuse it too often in different contexts. E.g. `appCloseButtonLabel` and `modalWindowCloseButtonLabel` could both have “Close” as the default value but would be still be separate.

Comment: @poke Ok, so if I got it right, you would write it for each use but specifying the resource key with not only the content but with the context ?

Comment: Not necessarily every use but for every separate context, yes. So this gives you the ability to translate different things differently even if they share the same English or default text (because that might not be the case in other languages).

Comment: @poke got your point ^^ thanks :)